# How to transform dyadic matrix to edge list

Tags: r, igraph, edge-list

I have a data like this

| Nominator | Nominees1 | Nominees2 | School |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1101 | 1104 | 1105 | 01 |
| 1102 | 1105 | N/A | 01 |
| 1103 | 1104 | 1105 | 01 |
| 1106 | 1107 | N/A | 02 |
| 1108 | 1107 | 1108 | 02 |

This is dyadic matrix. In each school, The Nominator have a connection with Nominees 1 and Nominees 2 with the id given in each column. I want to create 2 directed edge lists, each for school 1 and school 2 based on this dyadic matrix. For example, in each school, I want to have a matrix. This matrix will have the first column as a nominator and the second column is his/her nominees. I am new at R. I know igrpah has function to create graph from edge lists but not from this type of matrix so I want to convert it to edge list. Thank you so much

| Nominator | Nominees |
| --- | --- |
| 1101 | 1104 |
| 1101 | 1105 |
| 1102 | 1105 |
| 1103 | 1104 |
| 1103 | 1105 |